# MySQL - SELECT all patient that are prescribed X but NOT Y

Tags: mysql, sql, exists, not-exists

I have a database with a table that lists all medications that are prescribed for each patient.

I'm trying to filter to obtain patients that have been prescribed X but NOT Y.

Patient has been prescribed morphine liquid so they should also have been prescribed and an opioid overdose medication such as naloxone.

So I want to find all patients that have been prescribed Morphine and that are **missing** Naloxone.

I've tried numerous things, such as exists and sub queries but I'm struggling to get these to work at all.

I'm not overly confident with SQL and I tend to pull the data I need and then filter in a BI program.

The only way I can obtain this information currently is to do two queries, one that looks for all patients on Morphine and then another query that looks for all patients on Naloxone. I then compare the two and identify which patients are missing from the naloxone data.

It's all in 1 table, perhaps I can do a SELF join? A COUNT?

Table name is
`medorders mo`

columns used:
`mo.ID mo.surname mo.firstname mo.drugname`

| ID | surname | firstname | drugname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 294 | bloggs | joe | morphine |
| 294 | bloggs | joe | naloxone |
| 346 | mcdonald | old | morphine |
| 294 | mcdonald | old | bisoprolol |
| 567 | smith | john | amlodipine |
| 567 | smith | john | naloxone |
| 893 | Ansell | kate | levetiracetam |

From the small table above I'd expect to get back only:

- Old Mcdonald, as Joe Bloggs has the naloxone prescribed.
- John Smith has no morphine - ignore
- Kate Ansell has neither - ignore

Comment: So you want all people that have both 'naloxone' and 'morphine'? Those two static values? Or do the relevant drugs, that need to be prescribed together, come from another table?

Comment: you need a table where you have the drug name and if it is a painkiller or not, neither the database notr most peoüle now that so you need to provide the information

Comment: Sorry If I wrote question incorrectly. Want to pull every patient that is prescribed Morphine WITHOUT naloxone. Can be a LIKE for mo.drugname

Comment: The ID in the table is the patient's ID? (In that case it should be called patient_id or the like, because from a table's ID we expect it to be unique.) And you store the name in the table, too, so if Ann Miller married and is now called Ann Smith, we may find both names with her ID in the table? Which of the two names do you want to show in your results then? I suppose you have an additional patients table that the ID links to, where we can find the patient's current name and use this?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, I didn't want to use my tables actual names. You are correct that ID would actually be each individual patient identifier. I'm going to link other tables that contain patient information to this medorders mo table :). Does this change anything at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT ID, surname, firstname
FROM medorders
GROUP BY ID, surname, firstname
HAVING SUM(drugname = 'morphine') > 0 AND  -- prescribed morphine
       SUM(drugname = 'naloxone') = 0;     -- not prescribed naloxone
```

The two criteria in the `HAVING` clause are summing boolean expressions.  Each expression checks for the presence of one of the two drugs, and the sums are being done across all records for each person.

Comment: without a normalized table it will be tedious to write all drugs down

Comment: I checked 10 or so IDs and this seems to have done the trick. Would you mind explaining what this is doing? I'd be very grateful. Just in case I can adapt it for future.

Comment: @Josh S: The trick here that Tim forgot to explain is that in MySQL true = 1 and false = 0. You can hence add conditions (e.g. false + true + false), which would not make sense otherwise. So for `SUM(drugname = 'morphine')` you get 0 if this condition is false for all the patient's rows and a number > 0 if the condition is true for at least one row.

Comment: @JoshS: The only problem with this solution is when a person's name changes in this table. See my comment under your request on this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I kind of get it,  I think. How would I go about adding more drugs to NOT be counted. Just more SUM(drugname = 'DRUG') = 0; 
and keep going?

Comment: No...just add them to the sum expression: `SUM(drugname = 'Concerta' OR drugname = 'Ritalin') = 0`